# Am I in or at lecture?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is the correct for being present in /at  lecture?

"Sorry,  I am **in** a lecture now",  or "I am **at** the lecture now"?

Answer (score 4):

Both are used interchangeably and in colloquial speech I'm fairly sure nobody would correct you for using either.

Technically, "**at**" doesn't mean you are actually *in* the lecture. For example you might say that you have "arrived at the store", which could simply mean you have reached the exterior of the store and have not yet entered it. You may even use "at" when speaking about somewhere you have not yet reached, for example "I'm at a concert tonight". Saying you are "**in**" somewhere is much more specific.

To be completely correct therefore you should use "I'm *at* a lecture" when speaking about attending a lecture in the future or if you had arrived at the venue, and only use "I'm *in* a lecture" if the lecture is in progress.

Comment: Really? So, "Were you at the lecture, yesterday?" wouldn't mean that I actually attended it, but it would mean that I arrived at the venue.

Comment: @user1425 I said 'technically'. It would often be taken to mean you attended, yes. But let's say your cell phone rang and you left the room to take the call. You would say "I'm at the lecture!", even though you've temporarily left the room. If you said "I'm **in** the lecture!" your caller would likely assume you were still in the room.

Comment: Is there any difference in usage for a lecturer and a student? If I am a lecture, am I in or at a lecture? Or do they not differ in this regard?

Comment: @user1425 That's a different question entirely, have you done any research?

Answer (score 2):

@Astralbee has already answered but

In your context, I think that the correct one is

> I'm **in** a lecture now

If you're talking with someone using a mobile device and you want to hang up; or if you want to end a conversation because you have to go to the lecture, you can use some additional particle for emphasizing the present moment

> Sorry, I'm in a lecture **right** now. Byeeee.
>
> Sorry, I'm **currently** in a lecture. Byeeee.

During my "research", I found this in a students forum online. It seems that someone was a bit bored.

[image: Image containing the phrase: I'm currently in a lecture]

Comment: Do you have any evidence that saying "I'm in a lecture right now" means that you may not be at the classroom yet? That seems very unintuitive to me (native speaker). "Right now" and "currently" are pretty much synonymous (at least in these types of contexts), and I would interpret *both* those sentences as meaning that the student is currently in the classroom listening to the lecture (or, if they're polite, they've stepped outside during a lecture that was already in progress and which, up until the phone call, they were listening to).

Comment: @Sparksbet Ok. And you have downvoted just for that? Because one of my examples is "unintuitive"?

Comment: I mean, it was more than half the content of the question, and it was incorrect, so yes. I've removed it now that you've edited the answer.

Comment: @Sparksbet Half? I don't think so but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you are more likely to hear 'in a lecture' than 'at a lecture', although either version is acceptable, This is supported by this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+lecture%2Cat+a+lecture&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20lecture%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20lecture%3B%2Cc0).

Relying on my experience again, the use of 'I am in (a particular location)' or 'I am at (a particular location)' is inconsistently applied for different locations. e.g. I have often heard 'I am at the movies', but never 'I am in the movies'. To me, the latter implies that the person is an actor in a movie. Similarly, I hear 'I am at school' more often than 'I am in school', but I hear 'I am in class' more often than 'I am at class'.

Answer (score 1):

I would say *"I am **at** the lecture now"* is correct (though in practice "in" is also used (some answers here prove it)).

I'd use "at" because a lecture is a kind of event. We would say "I'm at the meeting" or "I'm at the concert" for the same reason. MyGrammarLab Intermediate by M.Foley and D.Hall explains it a bit differently though:

[image]

To support my "event" idea, I'd like to refer to English Grammar in Use by R.Murphy:

[image]

Here are a few examples like that with "at" + event:

> 1. Both my friends are **at** the lecture.
> 2. **At** the lessons in our workshop you will be able to make any flower - exotic, bright and unique!
> 3. Activities: Publication of compilation of speeches given **at** the seminar on international protection of human rights.

"In the lecture" is more like "during the lecture" (though my perception may be different from the one of some other people). See the examples below:

> 1. She referred to Professor Jones's work **in** her lecture on Shakespeare's imagery.
> 2. **In** the second lecture you will learn about it.

Given all that, I assume "I'm at the lecture" is more grammatical.

Comment: You can also say "in a meeting", for what it's worth. Both "at" and "in" seem equally acceptable to me, and James linked an Ngram showing that "in a lecture" is more common (and, indeed, it's what I would more likely use). Do you have any evidence that "at" is correct and "in" is more colloquial?

Comment: @Sparksbet Thank you for your comment. I've edited my answer. Please have a look. As for "in a meeting", we can say that of course, just like "I have went" (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449476/is-have-went-gaining-common-currency-in-ame-and-bre). Sorry for the digression.

Comment: Characterizing "in a meeting" and "in a lecture" as informal or non-standard like "have went" is simply not accurate. These are perfectly common even in formal written English. [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/meeting) uses "in a meeting" rather than "at a meeting" in its example sentences and includes "in" but not "at" among its collocations because, while "at a meeting" is fine, "in" is more common (both "in" and "at" are listed for [lecture](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/lecture_1?q=lecture)).

Comment: @Sparksbet Yes, I agree that "in a meeting" and "have went" are different. And I wouldn't doubt the OED of course. It doesn't contradict my answer actually. I've mentioned that "in" is used and to me it's more of a question of perception.

Comment: She referred to Professor Jones's work in her lecture on Shakespeare's imagery./ In the second lecture you will learn about it. - these examples don't talk about the presence of the person. They are different

Answer (score 1):

*At X* is used if X is a place.

Some properties of places are below.

- people can freely enter and exit at any time.
- it's a wide open area.
- someone could give you directions to it if asked.
- it's considered a public event

So using *at X* to refer to a lecture can usually work, especially if the place is dedicated to hosting lectures.

Can you be *in* a place?  You can be inside of its borders, fences, or buildings.  If a lecture is taking place at a lecture hall, *in X* would be reasonable.

*In X* can also be used if X has some notion of a session - sessions have a start and end (borders) and saying you are "in" them means you are there while it's happening.

Since typically all lectures are planned and have well-defined start and stop times (sessions), *in X* has a higher chance of being appropriate.